# Recycler View Item Deletion index out of bound

Tags: java, android, sql, arrays

I am trying to delete the item from the recycler view stored in an array.

final int position is giving me this suggestion (
Do not treat position as fixed; only use immediately and call holder.getAdapterPosition() to look it up later).

The Method I have written below is in oncreate, the item we want to delete is holded by holder and its  calling deletetask() method.

The actual error is items gets deleted without any exception, then when I try to delete more items, sometime I get the following error " java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size 0 "

then It push me back to previous activity, after coming again to recycler view activity the items get deleted without any exception.

why I am getting this error "java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size 0 "

```
FirebaseRecyclerOptions<model_tasks> options = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<model_tasks>()
                .setQuery(reference, model_tasks.class)
                .build();

        FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<model_tasks, Viewholder> adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<model_tasks, Viewholder>(options) {
            @Override
            protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull Viewholder holder,final int position , @NonNull final model_tasks model) {

                holder.setTime(model.getTime());
                holder.setTask(model.getTask());
                holder.setDesc(model.getDesc());

                holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                       key=  getRef(position).getKey();

                       // task_ = model.getTask();
                        //  description = model.getDesc();
                        //idd=model.getTime();
                        updateTask();
                    }
                });
            }

            @NonNull
            @Override
            public Viewholder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.task_recieved, parent, false);
                return new Viewholder(view);
            }
        };

        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.startListening();
    }
```

Delete Task (method)

```
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                reference.child(key).removeValue().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()){
                        //    Toast.makeText(tasks.this, "Task Is deleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                          //  cancelAlarm();
                        }else
                        {
                            String err = task.getException().toString();
                            Toast.makeText(tasks.this, "Failed to delete task "+ err, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }

                    }

                });
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer to the above question is instead of using position in key,  I just use the below line and it removed the crashing of the app.

`key=  getRef(holder.getAdapterPosition()).getKey();`